# beta distributions assigned to represent uncertainty

Tags: r, sensitivity-analysis

I need to calculate the Probabilistic Sensitivity Analysis for a function.
I was given this:

beta distributions assigned to represent uncertainty
And have this parameter with this data:

```
variable = d_progress
probability of variable : 0.1
n = 100
r = cases = 3
```

Now, I need to use this function or something?

```
p <- rbeta(n, shape1=alpha, shape2=beta)
```

I already have the parameters so I can find `p`.
If I have:

```
p<-rbeta(100, 1, 99)
```

What I do is I create a vector now? Of 100 values?
So, I need to create a loop, 100 times for the following formula:

```
for each of 100 p generated (
  EV = p*b_par
  I then submit each EV in a vector or something...
  I need to Find the different values of EV for different p,
    so I just find the mean of all the 100 EV in the end
)
```

Comment: You need to define the top four lines in your code. Need more context to offer help. The second like of r-code looks like you are creatig a vector of 100 beta-distributed values and assigning them to p. I presume this would be fed as input into whatever function you are evaluating to see the variation in output, for example, let p be as you defined then the sensitivty in a function $f(x)$ could either be $f(x+p)$ or $f(xp)$ depending on the form of your function.

Comment: I updated my question, please take a look, i finally understood something :):):)

Comment: Thanks. This is still not too clear. Please *explicitly* identify the function you want to check, the variables/arguments you are testing the sensitivity of, and what type of uncertainty are you modeling (percentage error or absolute errors?)

Comment: I am trying to do a psa sensitivity analysis... 
It'S like, i need to iterate the EV value for each of the p'S generated from the rbeta function...  sorry if i'm not too clear...

Comment: let's suppose i just want to create the vector with 100 values of the p parameter, then for each value of p i need to fund the EV , then create a vector with all the 100 different EV's, how am i supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on OPs goal of creating 100 error-dispersed EV values generated from a vector of beta errors:

Assumptions:

**Function**: EV($b_{par}$)= $b_{par}$

**Uncertainty type**: multiplicative beta-distributed, alpha=1, beta=99

**Number of realizations of the error:** n=100

You would do the following:

Create vector of p-values:

`p<-rbeta(100, shape1=1, shape2=99);`
  `EV<-p*b_par;`
  `mean(EV)`

If this is all you need to do, and if b_par is a constant, then you can take a shortcut and just say that $$\text{mean}(EV) = b_{par}\mathbb{E}[\text{Beta}(1,99)]$$ since expectation is a linear operation.

Comment: Great, thank you very much..
So i don't need to do a loop right? it takes it automatically?
And yes, b_par is a constant...

Comment: Yes, if you do it in R, it should handle it in one fell swoop. But note that you can simply calculate an exact value using simple linearity of expectation. Look up the mean of your beta and multipy by b_par to get the answer.

Comment: If you are Ok with this answer, just select it as answered so people will know to skip over it.

Comment: That was great, great, great :):):)
Thank you very much!